# LINQ to SQL - How to make this works with database faster

Tags: c#, performance, linq-to-sql

I have a problem. My `LINQ to SQL` queries are pushing data to the database at ~1000 rows per second. But this is much too slow for me. The objects are not complicated. CPU usage is <10% and bandwidth is not the bottleneck too.

10% is on client, on server is 0% or max 1% generally not working at all, not traversing indexes etc.

Why 1000/s are slow, i need something around 20000/s - 200000/s to solve my problem in other way i will get more data than i can calculate.

I dont using transaction but `LINQ` using, when i post for example milion objects new objects to DataContext and run `SubmitChanges()` then this is inserting in `LINQ` internal transaction.

I dont use parallel `LINQ`, i dont have many selects, mostly in this scenario i'm inserting objects and want use all resources i have not only 5% od cpu and 10kb/s of network!

Comment: Why is 1000 rows a second too slow? CPU usage is 10% on the server or the client? Did you do a trace on the server?

Comment: Writing at 1000 rows a second is a respectable speed, especially for heavily indexed tables or tables with triggers. If you think you can go faster, try raw ado.net calls and see if it would help (I doubt it).

Comment: Are you using transactions on the SQL server?

Comment: Post your code... and try using Parallel LINQ.

Comment: When you write to DB, your harddrive is nearly always your bottleneck. Don't worry about under-utilizing resources, your program  probably goes full speed, but your DB can write only so much data in a second. Is the 20000 writes per second speed sustained, or peak?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when i post for example milion objects

Forget it. Linq2sql is not intended for such large batch updates/inserts.

The problem is that Linq2sql will execute a separate insert (or update) statement for each insert (update). This kind of behaviour is not suitable with such large numbers.

For inserts you should look into SqlBulkCopy because it is a **lot** faster (and really order of magnitudes faster).

Comment: true, forget it is a good solution, performance in linq don't exists and nothing i can do with that, on sqlbulk copy works much faster

Comment: Linq is fine for selecting and/or manipulation of a few entities though. I use it a lot and am generally happy. But for my batch inserts (I am doing 120 million inserts in a batch) I avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

Some performance optimization can be achived with LINQ-to-SQL using first off precompiled queries.  A large part of the cost is compiling the actual query.

http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/speedinguplinqtosql.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399335.aspx

Also you can disable object tracking which may give you milliseconds of improvement.  This is done on the datacontext right after you instantiate it.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem before. The solution I used is Entity Framework. There is a tutorial [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399182.aspx). One traditional way is to use LINQ-To-Entity, which has similar syntax and seamless integration of C# objects. This way gave me 10x acceleration in my impression. But a more efficient (in magnitude) way is to write SQL statement by yourself, and then use ExecuteStoreQuery function to fetch the results. It requires you to write SQL rather than LINQ statements, but the returned results can still be read by C# easily.

Comment: Wow, when you are talking true with this 10x acceleration you are accepted. I will try that